# How do I resolve this Client ID Error from Spotipy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, spotify

I'm trying to do a Spotify project with python and I'm getting this error. "No client_id. Pass it or set a spotipy_client_id environment variable."

Here's my code:

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials

surfaces_url = 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/4ETSs924pXMzjIeD6E9b4u'

spotify = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=SpotifyClientCredentials())

results = spotify.artist_albums(surfaces_url, album_type='album')
albums = results['items']

while results['next']:
    results = spotify.next(results)
    albums.extend(results['items'])

for album in albums:
    print(album['name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to autenticate without using environment variables is using SpotifyOAuth and providing the following credentials:

```
spotify = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager = SpotifyOAuth(client_id = '',
                                                      client_secret = '',
                                                      redirect_uri = '',
                                                      user = ''))
```

Comment: Where would I get my Client ID? Thank you!

Comment: @TheMartian32 You should create an application at https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard/

Comment: Alright so the client ID thing works now, but I'm getting this new error Spotify0Auth is not defined.

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to say that you need to add `from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth` to the top of the code

Comment: Thanks again! But I swear to god I'm cursed today because that just threw another error saying that I have no "client_secret".

Comment: Ahaha no problem! Right after the client_id, add `, client_secret = 'your client secret', redirect_uri = 'your redirect uri (this doesn't matter but should match with the one on your spotify application, it can be anything like www.google.com) ', user = 'your spotify user id'`. You should be able to find this ones on your application at spotify, except the user id